# Excessive NonPaged Pool Usage

Tags: memory, pool, windbg

This is the output of !vm command from an hang dump. The system hangs every 3-4 days.

```
*** Virtual Memory Usage ***
    Physical Memory:    16774339 (  67097356 Kb)
    Page File: \??\C:\pagefile.sys
      Current:  68157440 Kb  Free Space:  68145560 Kb
      Minimum:  68157440 Kb  Maximum:     68157440 Kb
    Page File: \??\D:\pagefile.sys
      Current:  67404556 Kb  Free Space:  67394968 Kb
      Minimum:  67404556 Kb  Maximum:    201292068 Kb
    Available Pages:    10629840 (  42519360 Kb)
    ResAvail Pages:     11045894 (  44183576 Kb)
    Locked IO Pages:           0 (         0 Kb)
    Free System PTEs:      37825 (    151300 Kb)

    ******* 3334221 system cache map requests have failed ******

    Modified Pages:         2113 (      8452 Kb)
    Modified PF Pages:      1744 (      6976 Kb)
    NonPagedPool 0 Used:       0 (         0 Kb)
    NonPagedPoolNx 0 Used: 23925 (     95700 Kb)
    NonPagedPool 1 Used:       0 (         0 Kb)
    NonPagedPoolNx 1 Used:  2738 (     10952 Kb)
    NonPagedPool Usage: -2143215616 (8607006720 Kb)
    NonPagedPoolNx Usage:  61170 (    244680 Kb)
    NonPagedPool Max:     522988 (   2091952 Kb)
    ********** Excessive NonPaged Pool Usage *****
    PagedPool 0 Usage:     68479 (    273916 Kb)
    PagedPool 1 Usage:     29229 (    116916 Kb)
    PagedPool 2 Usage:      2538 (     10152 Kb)
    PagedPool Usage:      100246 (    400984 Kb)
    PagedPool Maximum:    523264 (   2093056 Kb)

    ********** 2 pool allocations have failed **********

    Session Commit:        11488 (     45952 Kb)
    Shared Commit:         11408 (     45632 Kb)
    Special Pool:              0 (         0 Kb)
    Shared Process:         6450 (     25800 Kb)
    PagedPool Commit:     100336 (    401344 Kb)
    Driver Commit:          2649 (     10596 Kb)
    Committed pages:     6164380 (  24657520 Kb)
    Commit limit:       50615224 ( 202460896 Kb)
```

My questions are :

1. How should I interpret the negative value of NonPagedPool Usage?
2. Shouldn't the sum of "NonPagedPool N Used" equal to NonPagedPool Usage?
3. Likewise, shouldn't the sum of "NonPagedPoolNx N Used" equal to NonPagedPoolNx Usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Excessive Non-Page Pool (NPP) Memory Usage of 3.9TB May Be Seen When Using Windbg Build 6.12.0002.633**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2509968